# React Native image from uri not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a mobile app, but when I try to acces my images from a specific uri it won't show them. But it only shows on the computer of my friend and I did the same.

[image]

Above the text inside the 3 blocks there should be a image, but I receive an error.

The code:

```
<Image
   style={styles.image}
   source={{uri: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/images/illustrations/' + illustration}}
   onError={(error) => console.error(error)}
/>
```

I don't know what is going wrong ...

Comment: Can you view the image when you open the uri  in your simulator's browser?

Comment: Yes i can view the image in my emulator's browser

Comment: how exactly uri looks after concatenation, is it available from browser ? have you tried to use different uri ?

Comment: Now I get the images idk what was wrong, but I think it is because I received 3 network errors now

Answer (score 4):

> You have to must give width for images in react-native. also check the path of image if the path is right just clear your metro bundler cache and restart it.

```js
<Image source={{ uri: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/images/illustrations' + illustration }} style={{ height: 80, width: 80}} />
```

Comment: I already have in a style but it is still not working

Comment: And I also cleared the cache, still not showing up

Comment: `source={{ uri: ... }}` will just support `https` urls and by the way you don't need the source attribute anymore, just use `src={{'http://10.0.2.2:8000/images/illustrations' + illustration }}`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried pretty much everything until I put width and height, and was like a miracle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to restart your metro bundle.

```
<Image source={{ uri: `http://10.0.2.2:8000/images/illustrations/${illustration}`}} style={{ height: 80, width: 80}}
```